# CodeIgniter - Where to place the logic for authentication (sigin, signup)

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

Firstly, I am not a software architect, so please bear with me. I just need a basic understanding, nothing highly academic or too pedantic (Thin controller vs Fat model and all those debates..)

So scenario is that I am helping a colleague build a signin and signup feature in an app we are developing. We are using CodeIgniter which is a very very simple MVC framework.

My colleague wrote signin and signup functions inside a controller and in those functions he also added the necessary DB queries and added a bunch of helper functions inside the controller etc.

Since there are so many opinions on the separation of concern within an MVC, I am thinking about below role for a controller:

Use the controller for getting user input, sanitising that input, invoking models and passing them the data, getting results and rendering views.

With this design in mind the controller would do something like:

```
$auth = new AuthModel();
if($auth->doLogin($user,$pass))
  loadView("welcome-page");
else
  loadView("login-fail-page");
```

And the doLogin() in the AuthModel will do the heavy lifting of querying the DB etc.

As a reasonably "Ok-ish" design, will this suffice? Or is it ok to just have the query and resultset looking and everything in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's "Ok-ish" but within controllers other than the signup/signin controller you will probably need a `is_logged_in` method. It could be used in other controllers like this.

```
if($this->authmodel->is_logged_in() === FALSE)
{
    redirect('login'); //the "signup/signin" controller
}
//good to go, do authenticated user stuff
```

I suggest you study a couple of established and well respected CodeIgniter authentication libraries to see how they work and are used.

1. [Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)
2. [Community Auth](https://community-auth.com/)

There is a very nice tutorial on using Ion Auth with CI [HERE](http://avenir.ro/authentication-system-with-ion-auth-and-ci3/).